# PhantomJS having trouble detecting elements being added to the DOM

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, spock, geb

When I run my tests in chrome they work perfectly fine but I really need to run my tests heedlessly in phantomjs. The application I'm automating uses primefaces and the specific web element that has been giving me trouble is the primefaces growl. It's a little popup alert element that appears to confirm a record has been saved successfully. The growl gets added to the DOM dynamically when needed. Sometimes my tests will pass with no issues and randomly other times it will time out and fail because the test doens't always detect the growl in the DOM. I need to be able to access this element to ensure its message is a success message.

What's the best way to wait and detect if an element has been added to the DOM?

```
void save() {
    WebTestUtils.returnToTop(driver)
    actionMenu.selectItem("Save")
    waitFor(30,1) {growlMessage.children().size() > 0} //TIMES OUT HERE, but not always
    growlMessage.close(driver)
}

void close(WebDriver driver){
    waitFor (30,1) {find(".ui-growl-item").size() > 0} //check that the growl item exists in the DOM
    List<WebElement> closeIcon = driver.findElements(By.className("ui-growl-icon-close"))
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    //phantomjs is picky, jQuery is required for the following script to work
    for(int i=0; i<closeIcon.size(); i++){
        //close multiple growls if present
        js.executeScript("jQuery(arguments[0]).click();", closeIcon[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: there shall be some equivalent to `element.isDisplayed()` to confirm its presence in the DOM

Comment: Yes but if the element is not in the DOM `element.isDisplayed()` will return a null element. That's why I'm using `element.size() > 0`.

Comment: so unless you have `element.isDisplayed() == null` you know its not there and you shall not proceed.